# Best way to loop inside an object with the key being a value inside the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state in react as following

```
state = {
    profile: {
      name: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:1 },
      industry: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order:2 },
      address: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false. ordere:3},
      crn: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:4 },
      website: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order:5 },
      employeesNbr: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:6 },
      phoneNumber: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:7 },
      userRole: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:8},
      personCheck: { value: false, isRequired: true, hasError: false, order:9 },
    },
  };
```

And I have the following logic that was using the profile values as keys

```
handleInputChange = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const { profile } = this.state;

    profile[key].value = value;
    profile[key].hasError = false;

    this.setState({ profile });
  };

  handleProfileFormSubmit = () => {
    const { profile } = this.state;
    let errorExists = false;
    const arr = [];

    Object.keys(profile).forEach((key: string) => {
      const element = profile[key];

      if (
        (typeof element.value !== 'boolean' &&
          element.isRequired &&
          isEmpty(element.value)) ||
        (element.isRequired && !element.value)
      ) {
        element.hasError = true;
        errorExists = true;
        arr.push(key);
      }
    });
```

How can I change the `handleProfileFormSubmit` logic to go through the foreach loop using the order as keys so it goes through them from lower to higher number. This is important because changing the input fields in the front end without changing the order in the state part makes undefined errors when passing values?

Comment: Looks like you are mutating state, this could cause a whole range of unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

For that you will have to do a sort first. Instead of `Object.keys(profile).forEach` do this.

```
let sortedKeys = Object.keys(profile).sort((a, b)=> profile[a].order - profile[b].order)
sortedKeys.forEach((key: string) => {
    const element = profile[key];
})
```

Comment: This worked fine, thank you very much. But a small question why did we give the sort 2 values of a,b?

Comment: @SImonHaddad the sort function receive a callback to define how to compare the numbers. in the callback you get two element, compare them and return positive if `a` is larger and negative if `b` is larger

Comment: .sort function accepts a comparator function `(a, b)=> profile[a].order - profile[b].order`.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort